# Is it possible for a pivot table to have a many-to-many relationship with yet another table?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

Let's say there is a `tasks` table, and a `user` table. A task can have many users assigned through the `user_task` pivot table, which has a field `is_done` which tells if an assigned user has done the task. So far so good.

Now let's say there is also a `subtasks` table, and each task can have multiple subtasks.

Now if we also want to save for each assigned user which subtasks they are assigned to, for example in a `user_task_subtask` table.

So all tables would like like this:

```
user: [id, name]
task: [id, title]
subtask: [id, title, task_id]
user_task: [id, user_id, task_id, is_done]
user_task_subtask: [user_task_id, subtask_id]
```

Using eloquent, I assume I could type something like `$task->users()->where('user_id', 1)->pivot->subtasks` to access all the subtasks of user 1 for this particular task. I tried this:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(User::class)
            ->as('userdetails')
            ->withPivot('is_done')
            ->using(UserTaskDetails::class);
    }
}
```

and then add an extra relationship on the pivot:

```
class UserTaskDetails extends Pivot
{
    public function subtasks()
    {
         $this->belongsToMany(Subtask::class, 'user_task_subtask', ...); // <-- what to write here exactly?
    }
}
```

But I cannot get this `subtasks` relationship to work properly. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea i would go with `parent_id` concept for the `subtasks` instead of an seperate table. so `tasks` tables would contain another field called `parent_id`.

Comment: What do you mean? `subtask` already has a field `task_id`. But I also need to store which user is assigned to which subtask. So that's why I need something as `user_task_subtask` as well.

Comment: That's exatly what i am saying you don't need create another table you can use the `tasks` table as a `subtasks` only the difference is that you can add `parent_id` field into `tasks` table